# SQL Package Syntax Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I am having a problem with locating my error on this TAPI that I built for my "Project Table". It is a syntax error because it will not compile,  I posted my code and errors below... If someone could lead me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
create or replace package body "PROJECT_TAPI" is
--------------------------------------------------------------
-- create procedure for table "PROJECT"
procedure "INS_PROJECT" (
  "P_STARTDATE" in date              default null,
  "P_PROJID"    in number,
  "P_EMPNO"     in number            default null,
  "P_PROJNAME"  in varchar2          default null
) is 

begin

  insert into "PROJECT" (
     "STARTDATE",
     "PROJID",
     "EMPNO",
     "PROJNAME"
  ) values ( 
     "P_STARTDATE",
     "P_PROJID",
     "P_EMPNO",
     "P_PROJNAME"
  );

end "INS_PROJECT";
--------------------------------------------------------------
-- update procedure for table "PROJECT"
procedure "UPD_PROJECT" (
  "P_PROJID" in number,
  "P_STARTDATE" in date              default null,
  "P_EMPNO"     in number            default null,
  "P_PROJNAME"  in varchar2          default null,
  "P_MD5"       in varchar2          default null
) is 

  "L_MD5" varchar2(32767) := null;

begin

  if "P_MD5" is not null then
     for c1 in (
        select * from "PROJECT" 
        where "PROJID" = "P_PROJID" FOR UPDATE
     ) loop

        "L_MD5" := "BUILD_PROJECT_MD5"(
           c1."STARTDATE",
           c1."PROJID",
           c1."EMPNO",
           c1."PROJNAME"
        );

     end loop;

  end if;

  if ("P_MD5" is null) or ("L_MD5" = "P_MD5") then 
     update "PROJECT" set
        "STARTDATE"   = "P_STARTDATE",
        "PROJID"      = "P_PROJID",
        "EMPNO"       = "P_EMPNO",
        "PROJNAME"    = "P_PROJNAME"
     where "PROJID" = "P_PROJID";
  else
     raise_application_error (-20001,'Current version of data in database has changed since user    initiated update process. current checksum = "'||"L_MD5"||'", item checksum = "'||"P_MD5"||'".');  
  end if;

end "UPD_PROJECT";
--------------------------------------------------------------
-- delete procedure for table "PROJECT"
procedure "DEL_PROJECT" (
  "P_PROJID" in number
) is 

begin

  delete from "PROJECT" 
  where "PROJID" = "P_PROJID";

end "DEL_PROJECT";
--------------------------------------------------------------
-- get procedure for table "PROJECT"
procedure "GET_PROJECT" (
  "P_PROJID" in number,
  "P_STARTDATE" out date,
  "P_EMPNO"     out number,
  "P_PROJNAME"  out varchar2
) is 

  ignore varchar2(32676);
begin

  "GET_PROJECT" (
     "P_STARTDATE",
     "P_PROJID",
     "P_EMPNO",
     "P_PROJNAME",
     ignore
  );

end "GET_PROJECT";
--------------------------------------------------------------
-- get procedure for table "PROJECT"
procedure "GET_PROJECT" (
  "P_PROJID" in number,
  "P_STARTDATE" out date,
  "P_EMPNO"     out number,
  "P_PROJNAME"  out varchar2,
  "P_MD5"       out varchar2
) is 

begin

  for c1 in (
     select * from "PROJECT" 
     where "PROJID" = "P_PROJID" 
  ) loop
     "P_STARTDATE" := c1."STARTDATE";
     "P_EMPNO"     := c1."EMPNO";
     "P_PROJNAME"  := c1."PROJNAME";

     "P_MD5" := "BUILD_PROJECT_MD5"(
        c1."STARTDATE",
        c1."PROJID",
        c1."EMPNO",
        c1."PROJNAME"
     );
  end loop;

end "GET_PROJECT";
--------------------------------------------------------------
-- build MD5 function for table "PROJECT"
function "BUILD_PROJECT_MD5" (
  "P_PROJID" in number,
  "P_STARTDATE" in date              default null,
  "P_EMPNO"     in number            default null,
  "P_PROJNAME"  in varchar2          default null,
  "P_COL_SEP"   in varchar2          default '|'
 ) return varchar2 is 

 begin

  return sys.utl_raw.cast_to_raw(sys.dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input_string=> 
     "P_STARTDATE" ||"P_COL_SEP"||
     "P_EMPNO"     ||"P_COL_SEP"||
     "P_PROJNAME"  ||"P_COL_SEP"||
     ''
  ));

 end "BUILD_PROJECT_MD5";

end "PROJECT_TAPI";
```

**Error**

```
Compilation failed,line 46 (21:08:15)
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BUILD_PROJECT_MD5'Compilation    failed,line 46 (21:08:15)
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BUILD_PROJECT_MD5'Compilation failed,line 46 (21:08:15)
PL/SQL: Statement ignoredCompilation failed,line 93 (21:08:15)
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_PROJECT'Compilation failed,line 93 (21:08:15)
PL/SQL: Statement ignoredCompilation failed,line 122 (21:08:15)
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BUILD_PROJECT_MD5'Compilation failed,line 122 (21:08:15)
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BUILD_PROJECT_MD5'Compilation failed,line 122 (21:08:15)
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Thanks

Comment: Double-quotes should only be used if the identifiers in question are in "MixedCase" or are "all_lower_case" - and both cases are bad practice, in my opinion. As all your identifiers are UPPER_CASE (which is the default in Oracle) there's no need to put them inside double-quotes.

Comment: Yes most of your errors are "WRONG number or TYPES" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your calling of methods.

For example this one:

```
 "P_MD5" := "BUILD_PROJECT_MD5"(
    c1."STARTDATE",
    c1."PROJID",
```

The order of the fields is wrong. It should be the other way around.

Comment: I think they all are. I don't have a database near me so I can't say those are all problems but I do think so.